# how to write this sql

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using mysql

there are two tables

**vote**

```
app_id user_id
2      1
3      1
2      2
```

**app**

```
id title content
1  xx    xxxx   
2  yy    yyyy
3  zz    zzzz
```

I want to sort app table by the number of user's vote . in this example , the result should be

```
id title content
2  yy    yyyy
3  zz    zzzz
1  xx    xxxx
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select app.id, app.title, count(*) as votes
from app
left join vote on app.id = vote.app_id
group by app.id, app.title
order by votes desc
```

When you do not want to have the number of votes in the output, you can do this as well (in sql server it is possible, so i believe it should be possible in mySql as well, but I haven't tested it since I have no MySQL here).

```
select app.id, app.title
from app
left join vote on app.id = vote.app_id
group by app.id, app.title
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: As you are using an inner join it will not return the application "xx" which has no votes.

Comment: modified the inner join to a left join.

Comment: As you are using count(*) instead of count(vote.app_id), applications without votes are sorted as if they had one vote. Also, you are not returning the content field.

Comment: I think count(vote.app_id) will return 1 for groups that have several votes.

Answer (score 2):

Group on the data from the app table to get a count of votes, and use a left join on the vote table to also get the applications without votes:

```
select app.id, app.title, app.content
from app
left join vote on vote.app_id = app.id
group by app.id, app.title, app.content
order by count(vote.app_id) desc
```